# Dropdown is not consistent in Selenium Webdriver 3

Tags: selenium, c#, chrome

I just updated my webdriver from NUGet this morning and I am having issues with the dropdown. Below is my code:

```
public static void SelectDDL(this IWebElement element, string value)
{
    element.Click();
    element.SendKeys(value);
    element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

The method is below:

```
public void AddPositionTitle(string value)
{
    positionBasket.ElementDisplayed();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ddlSearchTitle.SelectDDL(value);
    Driver.LinkToClickIsVisible(value);
 }
```

This was working until I have upgraded to Selenium 3 this morning. I ran this in chrome.

What happened was it typed slow and execution was so inconsistent. I am not sure if my connection can be a culprit of this. I tried not to use `Thread.Sleep` as well, but the `Explicit Waits` won't work.

Comment: have you tried downgrading back to selenium 2?

Comment: I am not sure how to downgrade the nuget package back to selenium 2

Comment: restore an older version from version control? :) you do use a version control system not?

Comment: I did restore it, but it won't resolve it. I did the thread.sleep and it does resolve it.